# App crashes on closing a Fragment due to running Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, listener

My Fragmant contains a SensorEventListener which should evaluate some Inputs by the LightSensor.

LightDisp is my View. I think it crashes because the Fragment is already closing but the LightSensor triggered the Fragment to execute this method that's still in work:

```
private void setBackground(int Backgroundcolor) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
    layers[0] = new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(Backgroundcolor,
            Backgroundcolor, Backgroundcolor));
    layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.screen);
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    LightDisp.setBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable);
    LightDisp.invalidate();
}
```

How to avoid this?
Using the LightDisp.post() method didn't solved the problem either.
PS: The slower I set the delay to the sensorListener the less is crashes. With SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST it crashes almost every time.

**LogCat:**

```
10-15 15:36:46.361: D/SensorManager(10304): registerListener :: handle = 3  name= GP2A Light Sensor delay= 10000 Listener= ch.steff_94.morseapp_beta.Input_lightsensor$1@418d52d8
10-15 15:36:46.366: E/SensorManager(10304): thread start
10-15 15:36:46.366: E/SensorManager(10304): =======>>> Sensor Thread Running <<<========
10-15 15:36:52.436: D/dalvikvm(10304): GC_CONCURRENT freed 390K, 4% free 14754K/15367K, paused 1ms+4ms
10-15 15:36:58.971: D/SensorManager(10304): unregisterListener:: handle = 3 Listener= ch.steff_94.morseapp_beta.Input_lightsensor$1@418d52d8 name = GP2A Light Sensor
10-15 15:37:06.711: D/AndroidRuntime(10304): Shutting down VM
10-15 15:37:06.711: W/dalvikvm(10304): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5d1f8)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Input_lightsensor{418d4c00} not attached to Activity
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:741)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at ch.steff_94.morseapp_beta.Input_lightsensor.setBackground(Input_lightsensor.java:133)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at ch.steff_94.morseapp_beta.Input_lightsensor.access$2(Input_lightsensor.java:132)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at ch.steff_94.morseapp_beta.Input_lightsensor$1.onSensorChanged(Input_lightsensor.java:281)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:635)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-15 15:37:06.756: E/AndroidRuntime(10304):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you doing this in your `Fragment`s `onCreate`? Or in `onActivityCreated`?

Comment: @AlexLockwood I'm doing this in `private SensorEventListener lightSensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener(){ public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)}`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a "Fragment not attached to Activity" exception, so my guess is that you are instantiating something in your `Fragment` before the `Activity` has been created. Figure out what this might be, and move it to your `onActivityCreated()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue:
I had to unregister the `Listener` befor I commited my `FragmentTransaction` and NOT in the `onPause()` method ;)